# Meteor Custom error message for duplicate key ensure index with the duplicate field name?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

is there an appropriate way to throw an error for duplicate value trying to insert ?

```
    mongoerror e11000 duplicate key error index
```

I am wondering how accounts package throws username and email exists error message, likewise there should be a way to throw error for duplicate key error index, rather than internal server error.

Help would be much appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: how and where (client or server) are you doing the insertion?

Comment: On Server side using methods and call from client.. That's the secure way right ?

Comment: it's equally secure to insert on the client, and if you do that, then the exception will be easier to display to the user.

Comment: For your info please read this blog post.. https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-methods-client-side-operations/

Comment: you are probably right. I'm not equipped to help you if you need to point me to such basic intros on meteor, right? ;-)

Comment: Don't take it that way :) I am just stating the fact of server side insertions.. :( down votes ?

Comment: I'm still not really sure what you are asking, but see whether my answer below is along the lines of what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the accounts package simply throws an exception in a method call if the user name already exists:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L977

On the client, you can just look at the `error` returned by the call, which will be the exception object (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call), so just make sure to throw a descriptive exception for yourself to interpret on the client.

Alternatively you could design secure `insert` rules and then just do all this on the client. Keep in mind that `insert` into a collection is nothing but a method call underneath. So the mechanism will largely stay the same. It's just designed with collections in mind specifically, rather than general method calls that are more free-form.

Comment: It explains what I am looking for. Thanks.. I'll dig more in to accounts-base